# Adding UISearchBar into tableView header as subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a custom header to `UITableView`, that has some buttons and an `UISearchBar`. 
The problem is, that when I try to use searchBar I get a message:

`setting the first responder view of the table but we don't know its type (cell/header/footer)`

Has anyone encounter such problem?

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding to the table via:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:customView]
```

If so, that could be your error. Adding subviews to UITableView requires that you add them either as header, footer, or cell explicitly. Try:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = customView
```

Comment: Not true. You can add a subview to a UITableView in any fashion you want, just like any other UIView.

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the simple steps here..

1. create a property for mySearchBar in your '.h' file and synthesize.
2. set its attributes in viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear method (or u can simply do it in the Interface Builder)
3. Use the following delegate method to set it as the header of your table view...

   ```
   – (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {                 
           return self.mySearchBar;
   }
   ```

Comment: @Bartek wants a custom header that includes a search bar, not a search bar by itself.

Comment: @Anthony: If you only want the search bar and nothing else in the header view, then this should work just fine. Please try this and let me know if it doesnt work out.

Comment: The OP doesn't want just a search bar, he/she also wants buttons. Your solution is wrong for the posed question.