# UISearchBar and tableHeaderView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uisearchbar

My tableView currently have a random image banner showing up in tableHeaderView.  How can I also add the SearchBar and Search Display to tableHeaderView in my table?  I tried to drag the Search Bar and Search Display over to the tableView from storyboard, but it doesn't show the SearchBar.  I would like to add a searchBar on top of the table (above the random image banner).  Any clue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the answer given here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040125/adding-uisearchbar-into-tableview-header-as-subview/12434826#12434826

Answer (score 1):

Make an UIView contains your searchBar and random image banner, searchBar at view's top and random image banner at bottom. Then set the view to tableHeaderView.

Comment: Yes! This also eliminates the weird extra color the add at the top above it. Good call.